# How to change the ic_launcher_round.png folder content?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image, android-icons

I am having difficulties in changing the icon of an Android app. I have followed these instructions:

1. Right click on the project
2. Select New -> Image Asset
3. Select 'Asset Type' as Image
4. Select Path of and .png image
5. Optional: padding, trimming etc.
6. Next and Finish

This changed the icon in `minmap/ic_launcher.png` content, however, this does not change the `minmap/ic_launcher_round.png` folder content. This results, if the Android System is configured to show round icons, the icons to be shown in this folder: `minmap/ic_launcher_round.png`. But I could not find the way of changing the content of that particular folder.

I have tried to select a round shaped image in the Path, but still did not work.

If I set my Android phone to display app launcher icons as square, I see the desired icon, however, if it is changed to round, then I cannot see the my desired icon.

Please guide how to change the round ic_launchers.

Comment: have you included the roundicon in your manifest @dhssa's ?

Comment: As a workaround you can change the name manually from ic_launcher to ic_launcher_round and then press next and finish.

Comment: I have included the round in the Manifest file

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The latest Android Studio generates round icons for you: Right-click the `res` folder, select *Image Asset*:

[image: round, square, etc, icon formats image asset]

See https://dev.to/_s_farias/how-to-create-adaptive-icons-for-android-using-android-studio-459h for a more detailed walkthrough (Credit of [@Guillaume Raymond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379243/guillaume-raymond)).

Comment: a good walkthrough that helps me : https://dev.to/_s_farias/how-to-create-adaptive-icons-for-android-using-android-studio-459h

Answer (score 20):

You can try to go on `AnroidManifest.xml` and change path

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

to

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile with 25 api and use "Legacy only"